# Intelij uses 100% of CPU -> vmware is extremely slow

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm getting an usage 100% when the Intelij is running. After 20 min I cannot do anything on VMWARE and then I am forced to supsend or restart VM.

I tried to remove `rm /var/crash/*` but it did not help.

May you please advice me how to resolve the slowness problems?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please contact IntelliJ IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide a CPU snapshot as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Try to temporarily disable all third-party plugins https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html